# XAML designer Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The XAML Designer  does not work at all. I tried all possible solutions to the problem. Double reinstalled Visual Studio, but it did not help. I even put on Windows 7 and there also a couple of times reinstalled the Visual Studio. I click through the right button in the menu, but I get only raw code. Now it gives an error "it is not possible to open this editor". Visual Studio 15.7.4, xamarin.forms.

Comment: There is a `Preview` for Xamarin-based XAML, but not a `Designer`

Comment: So i can't use Designer for Xamarin.Android? Only Preview?

Comment: XAML files, AXML has android layout file. But when I create a new Xamarin.Android project, i have xaml files

Comment: Ok, one more time, Are you using `Xamarin.Forms` XAML files or `Xamarin.Android` layouts files (AXML or XAML extension...)

Comment: Xamarin.Forms and XAML

Comment: No Designer for Xamarin.Forms XAML, just a Preview

Comment: But if I create Xamarin.Android and get AXML, I shoud use Android Layout file and Designer for this?

Comment: If you are creating "native" Android layouts within a `Xamarin.Android` project, then yes, there is a Designer for them and/or you can edit the xml-based files (typically called AXML regardless of the file extension)

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot!! How can I repay you? I'm new to this site

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no XAML designer for Visual Studio.

Comment: Then what is it ? https://imgur.com/a/Du2f6yn

Comment: that is for WPF/UWP, not Xamarin Forms

Comment: For Xamarin only Preview?

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the xaml preview to work, but it only does so on simple Xamarin components. I've never seen it work on custom components. This has been a problem for years. Unfortunately, I gave up and now just test xaml by running the App. I have not tested it out, but there is a Xamarin form inspector available if you upgrade to enterprise addition.

Comment: I second that answer. As soon as you use either custom components or use resources stored within the native implementations, you most likely will encounter errors in the xaml previewer and the xamarin live player.